# grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a 16GB USB for ISO image, a 64GB USB for installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on window 8.1 as an external drive. My internal harddisk has C: and D:

After enter 'Try Ubuntu' then click 'Install Ubuntu'. My boot priority set to external drive then internal drive. Boot secure and fast start up disable.

My 64GB partition as follows:

- (6GB primary, ext4, swap)
- (500M logical EFI)
- (remaining GB logical, ext4, mount as /)

Boot loader set as the EFI in my 64GB USB drive

Tried few time to install Ubuntu, it stopped at:

```
grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into/target/
```

Even I tried to repair the boot loader and followed most of the post but none can fix it.

Comment: Turning on secure boot solved my problem and Ubuntu installed properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04: grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/ error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934415/ubuntu-16-04-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-to-install-into-target-error)

Answer (score 0):

I followed this guide [UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_UEFI_partition) and I finally got the same error to go away.

If you read 1. **Boot mode matching** -- "If you're **dual-booting with another OS, the two OSes' boot modes should match**. Most computers that ship with **Windows 8 and later use UEFI to boot that OS**, so this configuration dictates use of UEFI mode when installing and booting Ubuntu."

So it seems like you need to download GRUB or get rid of window 8.1. I am not familiar with how to install GRUB, but this link will be useful [GRUB MANUAL](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/grub/html_chapter/grub_3.html).

I hope it helps.