# Dual boot Windows 10 (LEGACY) and Ubuntu 18.04 on separate Drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I followed this [Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate Hard Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives) guide.

I just got a second drive on my laptop. I have a old SSD that runs windows 10 and a new one that is completely empty. I followed the guide to dual boot ubuntu on that, but after following all of the steps. I boot straight to ubuntu, not even grub. In my BIOS, in the UEFI section I dont have the old SSD in boot order, because it is in Legacy format??? How can I fix this, so I can dual boot using grub? One possibility I thought of is copying all of the data from the old SSD to the new one, because it has the space for it. But I dont know how it will affect the copied data if the old one is in legacy format?

Comment: okay, so it would have been important to check if dual booting is cross compatible UEFI-Legacy : this guy's answer is very lenient : https://askubuntu.com/a/935838/307184 I say don't attempt this unless you are an expert. but one thing you need to be much less of a demi-god to perform sucessfully is to switch you windows 10 to UEFI:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfJep4hmg9o&feature=youtu.be&t=55
after you've done this you can simply run: `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y boot-repair` and windows should appear in your grub.

Comment: please let me know if this is the kind of answer you are looking for, if so I'll write it out as and answer and if it works for you you can mark it as answer this way other people can find this question-answer.

Comment: This worked for me. I used the windows built-in mbr2gpt in windows terminal and then used the repair tool in ubuntu and that worked nicely. Thanks for the answer

Comment: huzzah! \o/ I've added the answer to your question, could you mark it this, way this question has the solved tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, make windows 10 UEFI instead.

to do *that* use the windows built-in mbr2gpt in windows terminal or, alternatively, follow this video guide : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfJep4hmg9o&feature=youtu.be&t=55

once you've done that reboot into ubuntu and run :

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y boot-repair
```

this will allow both windows and ubuntu to appear in the boot menu.