# ubuntu 18.04.1 with Windows 10 dual boot - 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' error hell?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have Windows 10 and I am trying to install ubuntu 18.04.1 with no success. Here is my system info:

- HP Envy x360 Laptop with **SSD (with GPT)**
- I have 100 MB EFI System parition (installed with Windows 10) [Here is my Disk Partition table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a859h.png)
- Windows 10 is installed in UEFI mode
- Windows 10 **Fast Reboot is disabled**
- From BIOS **Secure Boot is disabled**
- ubuntu 18.04.1 ISO copied to USB using Rufus 3.1 in GPT mode
- On restart ubuntu USB loads fine as I clicked on 'Try ubuntu'
- Once ubuntu is running then I click on Install ubuntu
- And then I get this error:

***The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into / target/.
   Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.***

I have tried many times by selecting/deselecting options like 'install 3rd party drivers', 'install updates during installation' but I always get the same error.

I have searched on web and many users are facing the same error and I have tried to apply some fixes / workarounds (like disabling Fast Reboot , disabling Secure Boot etc) but none worked in my case. I have even tried increasing the EFI partition size to 500 mb but I still got the same error.

Could someone **please** suggest a solution for this problem. I thought ubuntu is a friendly Linux distro and its installation will be as easy as installing Windows... but its giving me some pains....

I would really appreciate some help here.

**EDIT:**

[Here is my Parted -l result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHkXv.png)

Thanks,
Maverick

Comment: Trying to install with internet connection?

Comment: Tried it with internet and without internet. same error !!!

Comment: Try the original 18.04 ISO and it should install fine without internet

Comment: I tried 18.04 and it was also giving the same error and then I downloaded 18.04.1 thinking may this bug is fixed in updated release.

Comment: Any help here plz... ?

Comment: Post results from Ubuntu Live ISO from terminal for `sudo parted -l`

Comment: I have shared the result in my original post (at the end link to image)

Comment: Some have needed chkdsk on ESP from Windows or dosfsck from Linux on the ESP partition. `sudo dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/sda2`  Then try fixing with Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I tried this too... still the same error :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04: grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/ error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934415/ubuntu-16-04-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-to-install-into-target-error)

Answer (score 0):

I would boot into the Ubuntu Live without installing and in terminal do one line at a time

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/boot/efi
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-signed
os-prober
update-grub
exit
```

Then see if you can boot into the install

Comment: Tried this. Executed the given command line by line. But getting the same error !!!